# Serialization of an object type enum contained in a serializable class

Tags: java, object, serialization, enums, extending

I am trying to serialize an object type enum declared in my serializable class. I have already red all topics here but I did not find an answer to my issue. I hope someone can help me here.
    I actually am trying to serialize 2 objects type SType and CbitSet but I get the follow result:

```
<rSIt>
  <sType>S_V_INC</sType>
  <bits/>
  <mHave>true</mHave>
</rSIt>
```

I am expecting something like:

```
<rSIt>
  <sType>
     <code>VI</code>
     <description>V Inc</description>
     <name>S_V_INC</name>
  </sType>
  <bits>
    <words>{long[7]@5285}</words>
    <wordsInUse>7</wordsInUse>
    <sizeIsSticky>false</sizeIsSticky>
  <bits>
  <mHave>true</mHave>
</rSIt>
```

Here is my code:

```
    @XmlRootElement(name="rSIt")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class RSIt implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5848959699974019999L;
        @XmlElement
        private SType sType;
        @XmlElement
        private CbitSet bits = new CbitSet();
        @XmlElement
        private boolean mHave = true;

        public SType getSType() {
            return this.sType;
        }
        public void setSType(SType sType) {
            this.sType = sType;
        }
        public CbitSet getBits() {
            return this.bits;
        }

        public boolean ismHave() {
            return this.mHave;
        }
        public void setmHave(boolean mHave) {
            this.mHave = mHave;
        }

        public RSIt() {
            super();
        }

        public RSIt(SType sType, boolean mHave) {
            super();
            this.sType = sType;
            this.mHave = mHave;
        }

        public RSIt(SType sType, boolean mHave, Integer bit) {
            super();
            this.sType = sType;
            this.mHave = mHave;
            this.bits.set(bit);
        }
        }
    This is the implementation of SType  class (it is an Enum class):
    public enum SType {
        S_V_INC ("VI", "V Inc"),
        S_V_EXC ("VE", "V Exc"),
        S_RP_INC ("RI", "RP Inc"),
        S_RP_EXC ("RE", "RP Exc"),
        S_V_AN_F ("VA", "V F All");

        private final String code;
        private final String description;
        SearchType (String code, String description) {
            this.code = code;
            this.description = description;
        }
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }
    This is the implementation of CbitSet class
    import java.util.BitSet;
    @XmlRootElement(name="rSIt")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class CbitSet extends BitSet implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 476550000000055127L;

        private static final long longOne = 1;
        private static final long long64 = 64;

        public CbitSet() {
            super();
        }

        public long[] toLongArray() {
            long[] longs = new long[this.size() / 64];
            for (int i = 0; i < longs.length; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++)
                    if (this.get(i * 64 + j))
                        longs[i] |= longOne << j;
            return longs;
        }

        public void fromLongArray(long[] longs) {
            for (int i=0; i<longs.length*64; i++) {
                if ((longs[i/64]&(longOne<<(i%long64))) != 0) {
                    this.set(i);
                }
            }
        }

        public String toBitString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int x = 0; x < this.size(); x++) {
                if (this.get(x)) {
                    sb.append("1");
                } else {
                    sb.append("0");
                }
            }
            return sb.toString();       
        }

        public void fromBitString(String string) {
            int pos = 0;
            for (byte chr : string.getBytes()) {
                if ('1' == chr) {
                    this.set(pos);
                }
                pos++;
            }
        }
        public void set(List<Integer> bits) {
            set(bits,true);
        }
        public void set(List<Integer> bits, boolean value) {
            if (bits != null) {
                for (Integer bit : bits) {
                    if (bit != null) {
                        this.set(bit.intValue(), value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        public void set(Integer bitIndex) {
            if (bitIndex != null) {
                super.set(bitIndex);
            }
        }
        public void set(Integer bitIndex, boolean value) {
            if (bitIndex != null) {
                super.set(bitIndex, value);
            }
        }   
    }

    Thank you for your help guys.
```

Comment: This is the result I get:

Comment: This is the result I get: <rSIt>
<sType><code>VI</code><name>S_V_INC</name><description>V Inc</description></sType>
<bits><words>{long[7]@5285}</words><wordsInUse>7</wordsInUse><sizeIsSticky>false</sizeIsSticky></bits>
<mHave>true</mHave>
</rSIt> and I am expecting <rSIt>
<sType>S_V_INC</sType>
<bits/>
<mHave>true</mHave>
</rSIt>

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking on [the edit link below the tags](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41365773/edit).

Answer (score 0):

I am also learning ... and I tend to agree with the answer from another SO question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28008030/1168041)) that

> `Enum`s in Java are meant to be immutable objects, in which case there
>   is no point in serializing any of their fields.

However, if, for any reason, that you insist to get the marshalled result as you have specified, I found that I could do that by changing `SType` from an `enum` to a class, and then embedding another `enum` called `EnumSType` in it.

The code looks like this:

```
package SerializationQuestion1;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

@XmlRootElement(name="sType")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)   
public class SType {
    public enum EnumSType {
        S_V_INC ("VI", "V Inc"),
        S_V_EXC ("VE", "V Exc"),
        S_RP_INC ("RI", "RP Inc"),
        S_RP_EXC ("RE", "RP Exc"),
        S_V_AN_F ("VA", "V F All");

        @XmlElement
        private final String code;
        @XmlElement
        private final String description;
        EnumSType (String code, String description) {   // Bug fix 1
            this.code = code;
            this.description = description;
        }
        public String getCode() {
            return code;
        }
        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }
    }

    @XmlTransient
    private EnumSType sType;

    public EnumSType getsType() {
        return sType;
    }

    public void setsType(EnumSType sType) {
        this.sType = sType;
    }

    public SType () {};

    public SType (EnumSType sType) {
        this.sType = sType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getCode() { return this.sType.getCode();};

    @XmlElement
    public String getDescription() { return this.sType.getDescription();};

    @XmlElement
    public String getName() { return this.sType.name();};
}
```

To instantiate an `RSIt` object, the code looks like this now:

```
RSIt rsit = new RSIt(new SType(EnumSType.S_V_INC), true, null);
```

The following was my marshalled output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rSIt>
    <sType>
        <code>VI</code>
        <description>V Inc</description>
        <name>S_V_INC</name>
    </sType>
    <bits/>
    <mHave>true</mHave>
</rSIt>
```

Comment: Thank you very much leeyuiwah for your quick response. The only problem if I do that is that, I will have to modify multiple projects that are using this enum class. I am trying to think there is another alternative...

Comment: No one has an idea regarding the CbitSet bits object ?

Comment: What is an example input?

Comment: What is the definition of `words`, `wordsInUse`, and `sizeIsSticky`?  And what does it mean by `long[7]@5285`

Comment: private long[] words;

Comment: Please give an example input.

Comment: These fields are from BitSet class that my CBitSet class implements. private long[] words;
    private transient int wordsInUse = 0;
 private transient boolean sizeIsSticky = false;

Comment: <bits>
    <words>{long[7]@5285}</words>
    <wordsInUse>7</wordsInUse>
    <sizeIsSticky>false</sizeIsSticky>
  <bits>

Comment: I looked through your code for `CbitSet` multiple times.  I didn't see it has the three fields called `words`, `wordsInUse`, nor `sizeIsSticky`.  There are only two constants called `long64` and `longOne`.  I realized that your `CbitSet` extends `BitSet`, but I don't think those three fields are exposed by the class.

Comment: Yes, that is exact leeyuiwah. I actually will need to declare an attribute called toLongArray that will get the value of the public long[] toLongArray()  method. So that I can get the long array value by doing this RSIt.getBits().getToLongArray, once toLongArray is serialized.

Comment: Even if `BitSet` internally has `words`, `wordsInUse`, and `sizeIsSticky`, they are internal to the class and have been declared `private` (not `protected`), so your class `CbitSet` does not have access to their values.

Comment: leeyuiwah, I am totally agree with you, that is why few methods like set are defined into my CbitSet class to modify their values. I was wrong when I asked my question at the begining but what I am trying to do is that I need to create an ettibute that hold the result of toLongArray() method and serialize this toLongArray data, because I need it. I really can not serialize CBitSetAgain thank you for your help leeyuiwah. I did something like that: private static final long longOne = 1;private static final long long64 = 64; @XmlElement(name="toLongArray") private long[] toLongArray;